# SDDM fonts not loading

Tags: qt, fonts

I have an issue with SDDM. When I use it with sddm-greeter in test-mode everything works fine. But after rebooting, I can see the theme but fonts are not displayed. Whatever the theme used I have the same issue.

I'm using Qt-5.9.0 and latest version (0.14.0) of SDDM.

Do you know how to solve this?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Same issue here. Tried to change SDDM font definition in a theme, but to no avail. Tried to reinstall Oxygen fonts, no change.